# Как создать правильное регулярное выражения для поиска записи денежной суммы разных форматов?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько вариантов записи денежной суммы, к примеру:

```
    a = '-1000000.00'
    a1 = '1000000.00'
    a2 = '1000000.00 rub.'
    
    b = '-1000000-00'
    b1 = '1000000-00'
    b2 = '1000000-00 rub.'
    
    c = '-1000000,00'
    c1 = '1000000,00'
    c2 = '1000000,00 rub.'
    
    d = '-1 000 000,00'
    d1 = '1 000 000,00'
    d2 = '1 000 000,00 rub.'
    
    e = '-1,000,000.00'
    e1 = '1,000,000.00'
    e2 = '1,000,000.00 rub.'

    f = '-1000000'
    f1 = '1000000'
    f2 = '1000000 rub'
```

Задача подогнать их все под один стандарт, который потом можно будет перевести вo float() - 1000000.00.
Хочу для этого использовать регулярное выражение, которое будет делить сумму на две группы - рубли и копейки, а потом использовать это для создания строки нудного формата. То есть вот так:

```
money = '1 000 000.00 rub'
match = re.match(r'^-?([\d\s]+)\.{1}(\d+\s*\w*)$', money)
dollars = ''.join([i for i in match.group(1) if i.isdigit() or i == '-'])
cents = ''.join([i for i in match.group(2) if i.isdigit()])
money_need_format = dollars + '.' + cents
print (money, '=====>', money_need_format)
# 1 000 000.00 rub =====> 1000000.00
```

Создать шаблон для каждого типа в отдельности не проблема, но хотелось бы найти шаблон, который будет универсальным и подойдет ко всем указанным типам записи суммы денежных средств.
Пробовал вот такой, но он в большинстве случаев загоняет и рубли и копейки в первую группу:

```
re.match(r'^(-?[\s,.\d]+)?[.\-,]{0,1}(\d{0,2}\s*\w*[.]?)$', i)
```

Какое может быть решение? Узнать заранее какого типа будет запись денежной суммы не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регуляркой возможно решить, как оказалось. Но в таких сложных выражениях легко допустить ошибку и что-то не учесть. Вроде ничего не упустил, но предпочел бы «руками» тупо пройтись по строке циклом и строго проверять-считать символы, чтобы наверняка. Или для каждого типа написать свою простую регулярку и каждый проверять отдельно.

---

Для разбора > https://regex101.com/r/WzaBtU/1/

```
import re

def money_format(string):
    #        (                g  r  o  u  p     1                     )(  group 3  )
    r = r'^-?((?:(?:\d{1,3})+)?(?:(?:([\s,])?\d{3}))?(?:(?:\2\d{3})+)?)([\-.,]\d{2})?(?:\srub\.?)?$'
    #                          (     ( gr2 ) →     ) (   → ↑↑       )
    match = re.match(r, string)

    if (not match): return None

    dollar = ''.join( re.findall(r'\d', match.group(1)) )
    cent = (match.group(3) or '.00')[1:]

    return dollar + '.' + cent

#####

test = [
    '-1000000.00', '1000000.00', '1000000.00 rub.',
    '-1000000-00', '1000000-00', '1000000-00 rub.',
    '-1000000,00', '1000000,00', '1000000,00 rub.',
    '-1 000 000,00', '1 000 000,00', '1 000 000,00 rub.',
    '-1,000,000.00', '1,000,000.00', '1,000,000.00 rub.',
    '-1000000', '1000000', '1000000 rub',
    '4555.15', '2.12 rub',
    '1 000,000 000-00' # <- отсеивает
]

for s in test: print(money_format(s))
```

`(?:(?:([\s,])?\d{3}))?` — первая группа вида `,000` берется отдельно, чтобы

`(?:(?:\2\d{3})+)?` — здесь через `\2` ссылаться на совпавший символ `,` или   и отсеить числа вида `1,000 000,000 000`

---

«В лоб» зато гарантированно без ошибки:

```
def money_format(string):
    # case: '-1000000.00', '1000000.00', '1000000.00 rub.'
    # case: '-1000000-00', '1000000-00', '1000000-00 rub.'
    # case: '-1000000,00', '1000000,00', '1000000,00 rub.'
    x = re.match(r'^-?(\d+)[.,\-](\d{2})(?:\srub\.?)?$', string)
    if x:
        return x.group(1) + '.' + x.group(2)

    # case: '-1 000 000,00', '1 000 000,00', '1 000 000,00 rub.',
    x = re.match(r'^-?((?:\d{1,3})(?:(?:\s\d{1,3})+))?,(\d\d)(?:\srub\.?)?$', string)
    if x:
        return ''.join( re.findall(r'\d', x.group(1)) ) + '.' + x.group(2)

    # case: '-1,000,000.00', '1,000,000.00', '1,000,000.00 rub.',
    x = re.match(r'^-?((?:\d{1,3})(?:(?:,\d{1,3})+))?.(\d\d)(?:\srub\.?)?$', string)
    if x:
        return ''.join( re.findall(r'\d', x.group(1)) ) + '.' + x.group(2)

    # case: '-1000000', '1000000', '1000000 rub'
    x = re.match(r'^-?(\d+)(?:\srub\.?)?$', string)
    if x:
        return x.group(1) + '.00'

    return None
```

Comment: А зачем отсеивать последнюю? В чистом виде миллиард же

Comment: @Namerek на всякий случай) Потому что не знаю, откуда будут прилетать числа и  как это надо интерпретировать (в списке допустимых такого варианта нет)

Comment: ооох спасибо) было немного сложно для меня, но вроде разобрался)